# Мультиязычный landing система сборки

Tags: javascript, html, json, gulp

Есть landing page контент вынесен в файл data.json в корне проекта, нужно прикрутить мультиязычность так чтобы переход осуществлялся по ссылке вида site.ru/en/ для английской версии сайта, а по дефолту site.ru/ была русская версия.
Я так понимаю что при сборке в папке build должна появляться папка /en в которую будет компилироваться html файл, для этого нужно создать ещё один json файл с переводом например data_en.json и настроить ещё один таск...

Вопрос как это собирать? Настраивать отдельный таск gulpfile.js? желательно увидеть пример, или может есть другие способы реализации?

Answer (score 0):

в папке /en должен быть index файл с прикрученным data_en.json, это может быть как отдельный файл так и роут, если у вас SPA с отдельным компонентом или условием для data_en.json. То что вы хотите сделать галпом, он этого не умеет.